# How can I get RabbitMQ running with docker?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, boot2docker

I am trying to run RabbitMQ in my Mac via docker. Such is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker_registry/repo:version
RUN echo "deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/debian/ testing main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    wget -qO - https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-signing-key-public.asc | apt-key add - && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y -q rabbitmq-server && \
    rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management && \
    echo "[rabbitmq_management]." > /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins && \
    apt-get -y autoremove --purge && \
    apt-get -y autoclean && \
    apt-get -y clean
RUN mkdir /etc/service/rabbitmq
ADD rabbitmq-server.sh /etc/service/rabbitmq/run
```

Here is the runit script for RabbitMQ

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1
exec /sbin/setuser rabbitmq /usr/sbin/rabbitmq-server >>/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit.log 2>&1
```

When I build against this Dockerfile,  I am able to get the RabbitMQ server running in any Linux instances, however, when run in Mac with boot2docker, the server can't start.
Below is the output of netstat when run in a Linux instance

```
root@44943337dccc:/# netstat -tan | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:15672           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5672                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::4369                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

However, with boot2docker,such is the output

```
root@5535e72r6ec:/# netstat -tan | grep LISTEN
```

Where did I miss or is this the issue with the boot2docker itself ?

```
~ ❯❯❯ boot2docker  version
Boot2Docker-cli version: v1.5.0
Git commit: ccd9032

~ ❯❯❯ docker --version
Docker version 1.5.0, build a8a31ef
```

Comment: You should probably start by looking for any errors that rabbitmq is giving you.  If you remove the i/o redirection in your rabbitmq-server.sh script, you can use `docker log` to see the output.

Comment: Couple of things you can try. Check if the rabbitmq service is actually runningin the container. If it is not probably your container has exited. You can try to run the script from the container manually as well. "docker run -it   -name="rabbit" <image id> /bin/bash", and once in the container you can run your script manually "/etc/services/rabbitmq/run"

Comment: @Zoro_77, I had already tried that too. However, rabbitmq fails to start and does not log any error/messages in the files it is supposed to write.

Comment: @all, I figured that out. 
I had previously installed Virtualbox via brew cask
    `brew cask install virtualbox`
I removed that and installed Virtualbox from a .dmg file and voila!
RabbitMQ works.